# Import a directory file by file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large number of csv files that I need to import and compare some of the fields to a list.  The files were/are generated every hour into the directory.  The analysis I want to perform needs to be applied to each file in the directory individually, not all of them at once.  Is there a way to take in each file one at a time?

Comment: Just specify a single file name to `sc.textFile` (or whatever you use for reading). Does that not work?

Comment: Yeah, that works no problem.  But I have something like 1500 files I would need to do that for manually.  Basically I'm hoping to automate going through each single file.

Comment: You could write a program to automate it... If you know how to process one file, just do that for each file. Sorry, it's not clear to me where you have the problem. Listing a directory?

Comment: @DanielDarabos "You could write a program to automate it... If you know how to process one file, just do that for each file." I guess this is what I will have to do.  I was hoping there was a way to have spark do that functionality.  
  
Let's say I have a directory `my_dir` that contains numerous files `file1`, `file2`, `file3`, ..., `fileN`.  I want to process each file separately, one-by-one (and append to a single results file) until I am out of files.  I am basically wondering if spark has a way to do that.

Comment: I'm still pretty confused :). But take a look at [`SparkContext`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext).`wholeTextFiles`. Maybe it's what you're looking for. It will process the files all at once though, exactly unlike you said. If you need one by one you don't need Spark, just write a `for` loop.